# Java class definition generics

Tags: java, generics

What is the meaning of

```
class MyMap<K, V> implements Map<Comparable<K>, V>
```

in class definition? I don't understand how `MyMap<K, V>` can be a valid implementation of `Map<Comparable<K>, V>` as `MyMap` needs `K` and `V` whereas `Map` needs `Comparable<K>` and `V`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-analyzing the declaration. `K` is just any type, and `MyMap` implements `Map<Comparable<K>, V>`.

> *[...] don't understand how `MyMap<K, V>` can be a valid implementation of `Map<Comparable<K>, V>` [...]*

It can if you implement the methods required by `Map<Comparable<K>, V>`. In particular `MyMap` needs to implement a method with the following signature for instance:

```
public Set<Comparable<K>> keySet() {
    ...
}
```

---

Note that the above method declaration puts no constraint on `K`. In other words the class declaration should not be confused with

```
class MyMap<K extends Comparable, V> implements Map<K, V>
```

which means that `K` needs to be `Comparable`.

Comment: This looks like a good answer. It would be interesting to see a typical usage for your MyMap class. As a starting point, consider the typical Java idiom:  

    Map<KeyType, ValueType> m = new HashMap<KeyType, ValueType>();

In the above, KeyType has to be comparable. However, with a MyMap, it doesn't. But then you'll have to declare it like this instead:  

    Map<Comparable<KeyType>, ValueType> m =
        new MyMap<KeyType, ValueType>();

Comment: Not sure I follow. A key does not have to be comparable in a HashMap.